# Retrieving inserted/updated row pk after custom save() method run in Django 1.7

Tags: python, django, django-models

As the title states, I need to get the pk from the last run query.
I have a model and I need to override the *save()* method so that another method from another model (which this one has a fk to) is called afterwards. Unfortunately, I'm being unable to get the pk of the last modified row within the *save()* method, and I don't understand why this is not working.

**Model:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.db import models

from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey

from apps.allegato.models import AllegatoTaratura
from apps.cliente.models import Cliente
from apps.strumento.models import Strumento

import logging

class Taratura(models.Model):
    cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente)
    strumento = ChainedForeignKey(
        Strumento,
        related_name="taratura_cliente",
        chained_field="cliente",
        chained_model_field="proprietario",
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
    )
    riferibilita = models.CharField(
        max_length=255, verbose_name='riferibilità')
    data = models.DateField()
    laboratorio = models.ForeignKey('laboratorio.Laboratorio')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        nuova_taratura = super(Taratura, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        nuova_taratura = Taratura.objects.get(pk=nuova_taratura.pk)
        Strumento.objects.get(pk=self.strumento.pk).aggiorna_prossima_taratura(nuova_taratura.data)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "tarature"
        verbose_name = "taratura"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'{} {}'.format(self.strumento, self.data)
```

Which fails with this message:
    Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pk'

I've also tried with:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    nuova_taratura_pk = super(Taratura, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # Call the "real" save() method.
    nuova_taratura = Taratura.objects.get(pk=nuova_taratura_pk)
    Strumento.objects.get(pk=self.strumento.pk).aggiorna_prossima_taratura(nuova_taratura.data)
```

but that's not working either:

```
Exception Value: Taratura matching query does not exist.
```

Any hint?

Comment: What's the point of this? `self` is already the object, why do you need to get it again?

Comment: Nice point. I was pretty sure I had been through that as my first attempt, but perhaps I was mislead by another error that now is following, and I probably thought it was still something with the _save()_ method. I'm not going any further with that though, as that's a whole different matter. Thanks for your effort @DanielRoseman.